# getConstructor() return a constructor that is not implemented

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I'm learning some of the reflection features in Java and I got a strange problem testing the `getConstructor()` function with this Class.

```java
public class IntegerSequence {

  private Integer[] elements;
  private int size;
  private int MAX_SIZE = 100;

  public IntegerSequence() {
    elements = new Integer[MAX_SIZE];
    size = 0;
    System.out.println("Hello Guys");
  }
}
```

The function returns a valid constructor but the "Hello Guys" message is never printed.

Furthermore, If I delete the constructor of `IntegerSequence`, it also return a valid constructor and doesn't throw any exception, even if there is no one anymore in `IntegerSequence` class.

I read that `getConstructor()` only returns a constructor coded in the class and not one made automatically by Java so I'm a bit lost.

Here is the code that use the function and it's output:

```
public void invokeDefaultConstructor(Class c){

    Constructor build = null;
    try {
      build = c.getConstructor();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(build.toString());
    System.out.println(build.getName());
  }
```

console Output:

```
public generics.IntegerSequence()
generics.IntegerSequence
```

**Do you know what could cause that kind of behaviour ?**

Comment: "*I read that getConstructor() only return a constructor coded in the class and not one made automatically by Java*" can you point out the source, because it may need correction/clarification.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted what was said, sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The function return a valid constructor but the "Hello Guys" message is never printed.

That's expected, since you never [call the constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) anywhere. You only get the constructor from the class.

> I read that getConstructor() only return a constructor coded in the class and not one made automatically by Java

I don't know where you read that. [The javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) certainly doesn't say that.

Comment: Aside from what was already pointed out, it may be worth adding that `getConstructor()` may indeed not be able to return default constructors. For instance default constructors have same visibility as visibility of class in which they are placed. So if class is not `public` default constructor will also not be public, meaning that `getConstructor()` will not be able to return it. Or when default constructor is inside *inner* class, because that would require from it to accept parameter of outer class, but `getConstructor()` specifies lack of any parameters.

Comment: Ok, thanks you @jb-nizet. So I think I didn't really get when a `NoSuchMethodException ` will be thrown ?

Comment: When you try to get a public constructor that does not exist. Again, the javadoc makes it clear: *if a matching method is not found*.